# Can't install Topaz SigPlus ActiveX control under Delphi XE. Have error messages

Tags: delphi, activex, delphi-xe, topaz-signatures

I'm installing Topaz's SigPlus ActiveX control http://www.topazsystems.com/Software/download/sigplusactivex.htm under Delphi XE Pro under Windows 7 x64.  This activeX control installs fine under Delphi 7.

I'm following these basic instructions http://topazsystems.com/Software/download/delphihowto.pdf

After clicking on OK in the final instruction, I get these errors under the 'Structure' panel

```
Failed to find standard type 'IInterface' at line 81 (81:5)  
Failed to find standard type 'IInterface' at line 292 (292:5)  
'GetTColorProp' is not a field or method identifier at line 478 (478:48)  
There are another 120 error messages like...    
'SetIntegerProp' is not a field...  
'GetIntegerProp' is not a field...  
'GetWordBoolProp' is not a field...  
'GetWideStringProp' is not a field...
```

and so on.

```
Expected a ')' but received a ':' at line 569 (569:12)  
Expected '.' but received ';' at line 579 (579:4)
Expected the end of the file but received an identifier 'CreateControl' at line 581 (581:20)
```

The first error "Failed to find standard type 'IInterface' at line 81 (81:5)" points to this code

```
_DSigPlus = dispinterface
    ['{69A40DA1-4D42-11D0-86B0-0000C025864A}']
```

The second error code "Failed to find standard type 'IInterface' at line 292 (292:5)" points to this code

```
 _DSigPlusEvents = dispinterface
    ['{69A40DA2-4D42-11D0-86B0-0000C025864A}']
```

Any ideas on how to get this ActiveX component to install correctly?  I'm just moving to XE (from D7) so I'm not sure the way to fix this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: The errors in the structure panel can be ignored (that panel uses a separate compiler designed to be faster but it has its problems). More importantly, can you compile the unit?

Comment: Run & Build are grayed out.  Are there any tricks or is Delphi XE significantly different in importing ActiveX controls?  Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

From the Main Menu select: Component\Import Component
Select “Import ActiveX Control” and press the ‘Next’ button.
Select “SigPlus OLE Control module” from the list and press the ‘Next’ button.
Select the “ActiveX” for Palette Pages: and keep the default values for the rest.  Press the ‘Next’ button.
Select “Install to New Package” and press the ‘Next’ button.
Enter “SigPlus” for the Package Name and “SigPlus” for the Description.
Click the “Finish” button.
Follow the Compiler prompts and verify that the TSigPlus component appears in the ActiveX Tool Palette.