# Can I use a .Net control instead of an ActiveX control under Delphi XE?

Tags: .net, delphi, activex, delphi-xe, topaz-signatures

I'm having a bunch of problems importing an ActiveX control into Delphi XE [Can't install Topaz SigPlus ActiveX control under Delphi XE. Have error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963927/cant-install-topaz-sigplus-activex-control-under-delphi-xe-have-error-messages)

Topaz also makes a .Net control.  Would it be better to try an use .Net instead of ActiveX?  Any gotchas or things to look out for?

Comment: Use your D7 _TLB.pas in XE and you should be fine. Introducing .net seems a rather drastic reaction. Did you talk to the vendor?

Comment: Thanks dude.  The OCX imported just fine.  I've had a running conversation with the vendor's tech support but it seems the combo of sigplus activex with delphi XE is a bit rare.  Any idea why D7 could import it correctly but XE didn't?

Comment: Type lib importer gets changed from version to version. Sometimes there are bugs.

Answer (score 1):

The more easy and painless way to use a Winform or WPF Control in a VCL Delphi Application is using [`Hydra`](http://www.remobjects.com/hydra/).